# WindowInsets vs InputMethodManager!! Right way to show and hide softkey in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, windowinsets, inputmethodmanager

What should i use; *WindowInsets* or *InputMethodManager* to show and hide the soft keyboard in android? Which is the right way of doing the cited task, without compromising the app performance?

I want the keyboard show and hide to be smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Go with InputMethodManager. I am using that in production. Did not face any performance issue.